# Ambiguious match exception in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a Controller derived from another Controller and both the controller contains method with same name. When I call a RedirectToAction from one of the method in Child Controller I get  "System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException:"

Below is the code snippet:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
 {
   [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return this.View();
    }
 }
public class UserController : AccountController
{
  [Route("User/")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index(Guid eventId)
    {

       return RedirectToAction("Register","User", new { eventId = eventId });
    }


    [AllowAnonymous]
    public  ActionResult Register(Guid eventId)
    {
        return View("Register");
    }
 }
```

I am calling RedirectToActionFrom the Index method of SubscribeController.

Route Config:

```
     public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");



        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Subscribtion",
            url: "User/{eventId}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Index", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: There are 2 `Register` actions in you `UserController`... (I suspect you've already know that). If you clarify what outcome you are looking for it would help someone to suggest an approach.

Comment: I want to redirect  from Index to Register(Guid eventId) .